# Why my Xcode failed to validate swift iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store-connect, xcode6

[image]

I am trying to archive my app and submit it to iTunes store. But I can't pass the validation.

Xcode always reported "Symbols tool failed."

I tried to archive and validate it by using Xcode 6.0 on 10.9 and Xcode 6.1 beta on 10.10 beta. Both are not working.

I will be appreciated for any help.

And IDEDistribution.stardard.log reported error like below:

```
2014-09-21 01:53:14 +0000 [MT] Validation failed for archive Europa with issues:
(
    "<IDEDistributionIssue: severity(error), error(Error Domain=ITunesSoftwareServiceErrorDomain Code=-21013 \"The archive is invalid.  /var/folders/dm/gps585zj4kvg0_9hlty6y8b00000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.FfM/Europa.ipa does not exist.\" UserInfo=0x7ff35a93a810 {NSLocalizedDescription=The archive is invalid.  /var/folders/dm/gps585zj4kvg0_9hlty6y8b00000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.FfM/Europa.ipa does not exist., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.})>"
)
2014-09-21 01:53:14 +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant
```

UPDATE: I find out that it can pass the validation when I uncheck "Include app symbols for your application to receive symbolicated crash logs from Apple" options. Does swift framework not support this feature?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by the following operations in Xcode.

I want to select a target on TARGETS.

I select the Build Phases.

I want to expand the Copy Bundle Resources.

To remove unnecessary files and libraries of the plug-in if it has been registered.

Comment: I am getting this same problem. But i don't understand this answer. How do you know if you have unnecessary files and libraries and remove them if the plug in is registered?

Comment: Indeed, I had a framework in resources. Basically, you have to remove all files from resources that are not xibs, storyboards, .xcassets, images, sounds, fonts, .strings, .plist. Unchecking the checkbox IN NOT the right solution.

Comment: I recently started using `Urban Airship` and somehow there was an `urban airship` folder in my `copy bundle resources`.  Removed that folder and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Urban Airship was the problem for me too. I removed the ```Airship``` and ```AirshipKit``` folders and it worked fine!

Answer (score 8):

I was having a similar problem - assumed it was a profile/sign issue with XCode 6.0.1 - however, your note to uncheck the 'Include app symbols' fixed the problem for me.

Comment: XCode 6.1 beta also has this issue, so weird.

Comment: Thought it might have been I'd made the build without the dSym, but tried again with that build option and got the same result...

Comment: Are you using swift too or just objective-c?

Comment: Obj C/C -- it was a Unity3D project I was submitting.

Comment: So I think it may be a bug of Xcode, not something like swift compiler.

Comment: This solution fixed my error uploading an app with four signed frameworks in Xcode 6

Answer (score 4):

uncheck "Include app symbols for your application to receive symbolicated crash logs from Apple". Organizer -> Submit...

Comment: How is this a solution? You'll obviously spot receiving symbolicated crash logs.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I accidentally had a static library in "Build Settings" -> "Embed Framework". Removing the static library from there helped.
There is also a similar question: [Client.ipa does not contain a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729582/client-ipa-does-not-contain-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

If the cleanup of "Copy Bundle Resources" didn't work for you, check if Link time Optimisation is switched on for your release build. Set it to NO.