# Client.ipa does not contain a file

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store

I am pulling my hair out on this error since the past few days. When I try to submit my cordova based iOS app I get an error that Symbols tool failed. This is What i have in my logs:

```
<IDEDistributionIssue: severity(error), error(Error Domain=ITunesSoftwareServiceErrorDomain Code=-19066 \"The path '/var/folders/sp/fhnmn9hd76vbdl523pf37krw0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.8PQ/Packages/Healthpick Client.ipa' does not contain a file.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The path '/var/folders/sp/fhnmn9hd76vbdl523pf37krw0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.8PQ/Packages/Healthpick Client.ipa' does not contain a file., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.})>
```

Here is a screenshot of the said error upon trying to submit to the app store:

[image: Stupid Error]

Please help.

Comment: "I get an error that Symbols tool failed".  Lets focus on that then; please provide the error messages.

Comment: this is the error: 

<IDEDistributionIssue: severity(error), error(Error Domain=ITunesSoftwareServiceErrorDomain Code=-19066 \"The path '/var/folders/sp/fhnmn9hd76vbdl523pf37krw0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.8PQ/Packages/Healthpick Client.ipa' does not contain a file.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The path '/var/folders/sp/fhnmn9hd76vbdl523pf37krw0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.8PQ/Packages/Healthpick Client.ipa' does not contain a file., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.})>

Comment: That isn't what I asked.  You mentioned an error with the symbols tool.

Comment: The above is the error I copied from the logs when the upload fails. This error is what the symbols tool shows:

The path '/var/folders/sp/fhnmn9hd76vbdl523pf37krw0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.8PQ/Packages‌​/Healthpick Client.ipa' does not contain a file.

Comment: So that is the error from the symbols tool?  Without more information there isn't much anyone else can do.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error because there were several static libraries (libXXX.a) erroneously included in the app's package. They were showing in the final upload confirmation box (listing Entitlements & Certificates), under the main .App.

My solution was to remove all references to those static libs from the project, adding them manually in the linker flags and library search paths.

There is certainly a better solution to prevent those files from being included. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable about Xcode can chime in.

Comment: My app is based on cordova and this is what i see in entitlements:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qo13ew57qtdzsee/Screenshot%202015-11-22%2023.39.55.png?dl=0

Any idea on how to remove them from there?

Comment: A quick update that I can submit builds of the same project via Xcode 6 without any issues. So its more like a Xcode 7 issue

Comment: It's not necessary to manually manage the linker inputs, you just need to set "skip install" to YES on the static library projects and/or targets.

Comment: for my case, the .a file was accidentally added into Targets > Build Phases > "Copy Bundle Resources" which was within a folder that i added

Answer (score 4):

I had the same symptoms as Benoit, and was able to remove the erroneously showing libXXX.a files from the app's package by doing the following:

1. Select the main project file
2. Select the app's target
3. Select "Build Phases"
4. Select "Copy Bundle Resources"
5. Remove any items related to the lib files that had been showing up in the app's target previously. In my case it was files related to Flurry.

Comment: This solution worked for me. This error occurred for me while I was updating an existing library in my project. Removing the files from library from this pane is what solved it for me. Thanks for the detailed steps.

Answer (score 0):

**Untick:**

Include app symbols for your application on Validate and upload to App Store.

And Bitcode.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to get this on XCode 8.3.1 when uploading an archive when my device is connected.  When I unplug my device and try again it works.